# How to check if valid excel file in python xlrd library

Tags: python, excel, xlrd

Is there any way with **xlrd** library to check if the file you use is a valid excel file? I know there's other libraries to check headers of files and I could use file extension check. But for the sake of **multiplatformness** I wonder if there's any function I could use in the **xlrd** library itself that could just return something like false when trying to open the file and then notify the user.

I'm kind of new on Python so I tried getting something debugging the `xlrd.open_workbook` function with no success.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can try to open workbook but in try/except block to catch `XLRDError` exception in case if file format not supported:

```
>>> from xlrd import open_workbook, XLRDError
>>> try:
...     book = open_workbook('test.txt')
... except XLRDError as e:
...     print e
... 
Unsupported format, or corrupt file: Expected BOF record; found '--index-'
```

or use a simple function:

```
from xlrd import open_workbook, XLRDError

def test_book(filename):
    try:
        open_workbook(filename)
    except XLRDError:
        return False
    else:
        return True
```

Comment: I used the function, it works! thanks, I just would suggest you add xlrd. before open_workbook to your asnwer so other users will find this answer ready to go.