# xlrd - issue on opening file

Tags: python, excel, xlrd

I'm using **xlrd 0.9.4** and I would like verify if the file that I must open is valid.

To do this, I wrote this code [in according with this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28645167/how-to-check-if-valid-excel-file-in-python-xlrd-library):

```
try:
    book = xlrd.open_workbook(file_path)
    print "Done"
except XLRDError:
    print "Wrong type of file."
```

where **file_path** is the path of my file.

This works fine, the problem is the following. First of all I have a valid .xls file, so script prints *Done*. Now, assume that the valid .xls file is renamed (also extension), for example from test.xls to test.txt.

If I run the script, i have the same result (*Done*).

Instead, if I use a "real" .txt file (empty or with some text), the script prints *Wrong type of file.*

This behavior happens because the "structure" of the file is not changed? Am I doing something wrong? There is another type of Exception that I can add to **except** branch?

Thanks in advance

Comment: you could use `if file_path.endswith(".xls") or file_path.endswith(".xlsx"):` to test for the extension.

Comment: What do you mean by "valid"?

Comment: What exactly about this behaviour is not how you'd expect it? Makes complete sense to me. The name/extension of a file has *nothing* to do with its content. In fact - input could even be a `StringIO` object so wouldn't even have a physical filename... You're asking the library if it can  process the data as a valid workbook and the above code does exactly that...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can see how to xlrd check the file before reading. In [xldr source](https://github.com/python-excel/xlrd/blob/master/xlrd/compdoc.py) at lines 18-19 defined a «magic» bytes. First bytes of file compared with this byte sequence at line 85. If its not equal exception will be rise. File extention not involved.

Signatures for different file types can be found [there](http://www.garykessler.net/library/file_sigs.html).